# Remove augroups around autocmds in .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

For each `autocmd` (or set of related autocommands) in my `.vimrc` I currently define an `augroup` to [prevent having multiple autocommands when I re-source my `.vimrc`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html). I do *not* need the `augroup` for anything else (e.g. toggling them on or off via settings).

Can I just remove all the `augroup` and `autocmd!` clutter surrounding my actual `autocmd` and tell Vim to remove all autocommands upon re-sourcing?

Perhaps adding something similar to the following line on top of my `.vimrc` (to unset all previous autocommands)?

```
autocmd! * *
```

*(Putting all autocommands in one `augroup` is no viable option for me, as I lose my structure then)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding `autocmd!` before defining your autocommands, and without any augroup, should be enough.

Here is an excerpt from `:h :autocmd` :

> When your .vimrc file is sourced twice, the autocommands will appear
>   twice. To avoid this, put this command in your .vimrc file, before
>   defining autocommands:
>
> :autocmd!   " Remove ALL autocommands for the current group.

I think that if you don't have any group, and you put `autocmd!` inside your vimrc, vim considers that it's inside a default group, and so will delete all the autocommands for the latter which is all autocommands globally, because of this (`:h autocmd-groups`) :

> When no specific group is selected, Vim uses the default group.  The
>   default group does not have a name.  You cannot execute the
>   autocommands from the default group separately; you can execute them
>   only by executing autocommands for all groups.

But if you want to be sure, there's a way to check.

Add this code in a file that is sourced by vim, for example your `~/.vimrc` (it will create the `:RedirInTab` command) :

```
function! RedirInTab(command)
    redir => s:output
    silent! execute a:command
    redir END
    if empty(s:output)
        echoerr "No output"
    else
        tabnew
        setlocal ft=help buftype=nofile noswapfile nobuflisted bufhidden=wipe nomodified
        silent! put=s:output
    endif
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command RedirInTab call RedirInTab(<q-args>)
```

To see all the autocommands installed in your session, you can type `:autocmd`.

But to navigate more easily in the output with the same commands you have in a normal buffer, and to see the number of lines contained in it, type this :

```
:RedirInTab autocmd
```

You'll see all your currently installed autocommands in a normal buffer displayed in a new tab (it works for any other command that gives an output, like `:command`, `:function`, `:highlight`, etc.). Go at the bottom of the buffer to see how many lines there are (hit `<C-g>` or `set number` if necessary).

Next source your `~/.vimrc` a few times (let's say 10). You can source it manually with `:so%` and you can repeat this command 10 times by typing `10@:`.
Now reexecute `:RedirInTab autocmd` and see how many lines there are this time.

If you don't put `autocmd!` in your `~/.vimrc`, you should probably see a few hundred more lines.
If you put `autocmd!`, the number of lines should be approximately the same.