# How can I tell if I'm in the command window?

Tags: command-line-window

Extremely related to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/prevent-focusgained-autocmd-running-in-command-line-editing-mode) except the answer there doesn't work

I get the following error when entering command-line editing mode `q:` or `Ctrl-F` (when already in command mode)

```
Error detected while processing CursorHold Auto commands for "*":
E11: Invalid in command-line window; <CR> executes, CTRL-C quits:  checktime | endif
```

The relevant section of my .vimrc is

```
"automatically reload file when changes detected
set autoread "this doesn't work on it's own!

"https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim/383044#383044
"on these events, any filename... and not in command mode then check files for changes
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if mode() != 'c' | checktime | endif

" Notification after file change
autocmd FileChangedShellPost *
  \ echohl WarningMsg | echo "File changed on disk. Buffer reloaded." | echohl None
```

So my question is how do I detect that I'm in the command-line window and stop that command from running there?

After a bit of reading `:h command-line` I tried replacing the condition with

```
if mode() != 'c' && getcmdwintype() == ''
```

but I'm still seeing the same issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Could you try to put only the relevant section of your vimrc in a separate file (e.g. `~/test.vimrc`), start vim with `vim -u ~/test.vimrc` and confirm that you still get the error. If you don't get the error maybe the problem comes from another autocmd.

Comment: @statox I'm running vim 8 ```VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct 20 2017 11:15:05)
Included patches: 1-1207
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org```
it seems a little surprising that the other answer clearly worked for someone else but isn't for me - could be a version thing maybe

Comment: I don't think this is a version problem. Are you sure you're not using another autocmd with the `CursorHold` event which would cause a problem?

Comment: @statox I've resolved now, see my answer.  it turns out that Ale has something in there aswell, I don't think it's relevant though

Answer (score 7):

Based on Luc's help I ended up going with this:

```
autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if !bufexists("[Command Line]") | checktime | endif
```

The reason this works is that the Command Line window is fairly modal so you can't have one accidentally open in the background - you will only get that buffer if you are actively editing in the command-line-window

The only caveat here is that if you save a buffer with that name, which I did accidentally at some point when messing around with this stuff - in which case the Command line window complains when it gets opened and instead gets named `"[Scratch]"` or something.

It's also worth noting that you should probably have something like this at the very top of your .vimrc as autocmds are just added to a list and if you are developing them you can end up with your [old ones kicking around](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/remove-augroups-around-autocmds-in-vimrc).

```
"clear out previous autocmds to stop them being duplicated when resourcing
"this file
autocmd!
```

I also learned you can list all autocmds by doing `:autocmd` and list for a specific event like:

```
:autocmd CursorHold
--- Auto-Commands ---
ALECursorGroup  CursorHold
    *         call ale#cursor#EchoCursorWarningWithDelay()
CursorHold
    *         if !bufexists("[Command Line]") | checktime | endif
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Regarding `au!`, indeed this is a good practice, but don't forget to put your autocommands in a group in order to clear only the auto-commands from this precise group.

Comment: I second @LucHermitte. Without specifically defining a group (in the command or via `:augroup`), your `autocmd!` will delete all the autocommands in the default group, which, depending on your config, could be a lot!

Comment: @Rich is that to cover the case that there is more than one vimrc (eg a system one) introducing autocmds?

Comment: Nope. I tried it in my config and it deleted quite a few hat had been added by plugins.

Comment: @Rich that's interesting, I'm using vim-plug to manage my plugins, I'm unsure whether they are effected (but maybe the ale one above would suggest otherwise). I don't know what the usual load order is without a plugin manager though

Comment: The main issue doesn't occur on first run, but if you source your `vimrc` in an existing Vim instance (so the way you load your plugins doesn't affect things). If you want to see which autocommands it would delete, you can run the following commands in a fresh instance of Vim: 1. `:redir > before.txt` 2. `:autocmd` 3: `:redir >  after.txt` 4. `:autocmd!` 5. `:autocmd` 6. `redir END`. And then quit Vim and run `vimdiff before.txt after.txt`

Answer (score 3):

`bufname('%')` returns `"[Command Line]"` in my case. I don't know if there is another information elsewhere.

You could also listen for `CmdwinEnter` and `CmdwinLeave` events and maintain an internal state that'll tell you in which mode you are.

EDIT: Here is what I would do. Note, this is completely untested. This may not work.

```
" ==== file: autoload/cmdlinewindow.vim
" Initialize to 0, keep the current state if the script is reloaded
let s:is_opened = get(s:, 'is_opened', 0)

function! cmdlinewindow#_enter() abort
    call lh#assert#false(s:is_opened)
    let s:is_opened = 1
endfunction

function! cmdlinewindow#_leave() abort
    call lh#assert#true(s:is_opened)
    let s:is_opened = 0
endfunction

function! cmdlinewindow#is_opened()
    return s:is_opened
endfunction

" ==== file: plugin/cmdlinewindow.vim
aug WatchCmdLineWindow
    au!
    au CmdwinEnter * call cmdlinewindow#_enter()
    au CmdwinLeave * call cmdlinewindow#_leave()
aug END
```

Then, from elsewhere, you'd just have to check cmdlinewindow#is_opened() result.

NB: [`lh#assert#...()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/DbC.md) comes from my vim script library. They are not needed, yet they state in which state I expect to be when calling these functions.

Comment: Nice one with bufname, I get the same result, however if I add that to the autocmd like `&& bufname('%')  != "[Command Line]"` I still see the same error after saving and resourcing my .vimrc

Comment: In that case, it's possible you're not using the right buf-expression. Try with `bufname('<abuf>')` instead. I can never remember which autocommands require us to use `<abuf>` instead of `%`.

Comment: If this still doesn't work, you can listen for the Enter/Leave events

Comment: I couldn't get either of those working, with the events probably because of my limited understanding of vim's variables... ended up going with `!bufexists("[Command Line]")`.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue as you. There are some discussions [here](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify/issues/231) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710305/error-when-attempting-to-go-back-to-normal-mode-in-vim-command-line-window/4710486#4710486). It seems that we can use `getcmdwintype()` to check if we are in command line window. Here is my working setting:

```
augroup auto_read
    autocmd!
    autocmd FocusGained,BufEnter,CursorHold,CursorHoldI *
                \ if mode() == 'n' && getcmdwintype() == '' | checktime | endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: Turns out, additionally to the mentioned approaches (which would qualify as hacks in my book) you can simply use `getcmdwintype()`. Credits to user micbou from the Youcompleteme maintainers. Docs:

```
getcmdwintype()
        Return the current |command-line-window| type. Possible return
        values are the same as |getcmdtype()|. Returns an empty string
        when not in the command-line window.
```